# FullCalendar Change Week View to Vertical List instead of Horizontal Table Columns

Tags: fullcalendar

Anyway to change the way the Days show in the Week View? I'd rather see a vertical list of the vents by day instead of the horizontal table view of the days. reasoning is it looks pretty bad when on mobile devices and any devices with small width screens...

If the only way to do this is through modifying the underlying code, where in the code creates the table content for the Week view? If I figure out where that is, I could probably modify it to display as a list instead of a table...

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I expanded on the below and came up with a better solution, with labels for each day.

Here's an updated example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nomatteus/dVGN2/3/

[image: example screenshot]

---

Here's a link to my answer in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nomatteus/VSXSB/2/

There is no way to do this without modifying the source code. However, you can make a simple edit to display the days vertically. In the `BasicWeekView.js` file, change

```
renderBasic(1, colCnt, false);
```

to

```
renderBasic(colCnt, 1, false);
```

For reference, the `renderBasic` function paramaters are `rowCount`, `colCount`, `showNumbers`.

I'd recommend copying the BasicWeekView code and use it to make your own view, so you can make other modifications as necessary (and also still have access to the basic week view).

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific? I have compared your code with the official fullcalendar.js, found from line 4539 of your code to 5377 are added by you, I was just expecting it should be much simpler, should be just modifying one view function

Comment: Trying to do this with the new version (v2) any ideas? Seems like it will be quite a few more changes...

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing with my calendar. On a mobile screen the horizontal layout is not very usable. With the current version of FullCalendar (2.1.1) I was able to create a vertical layout that looks half-decent:

[image: calendar]

Do this:

Change the **fullcalendar.js** file by adding this just below the code for the "BasicWeekView":

```
/* A week view with simple day cells running vertically
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

fcViews.vertWeek = VertWeekView; // register this view

function VertWeekView(calendar) {
    BasicView.call(this, calendar); // call the super-constructor
}

VertWeekView.prototype = createObject(BasicView.prototype); 
$.extend(VertWeekView.prototype, {
    name: 'vertWeek',

    incrementDate: function(date, delta) {
        return date.clone().stripTime().add(delta, 'weeks').startOf('week');
    },

    render: function(date) {
        this.intervalStart = date.clone().stripTime().startOf('week');
        this.intervalEnd = this.intervalStart.clone().add(1, 'weeks');

        this.start = this.skipHiddenDays(this.intervalStart);
        this.end = this.skipHiddenDays(this.intervalEnd, -1, true);

        this.title = this.calendar.formatRange(
            this.start,
            this.end.clone().subtract(1), // make inclusive by subtracting 1 ms
            this.opt('titleFormat'),
            ' \u2014 ' // emphasized dash
        );

        BasicView.prototype.render.call(this, this.getCellsPerWeek(), 1,  true); 
    }
});
;;
```

Add this **CSS** to your page:

```
.fc-vertweek-header {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.fc-vertweek-day {
    float: right; 
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Now in your **javascript** call to `fullCalendar` specify these two things:

```
defaultView: vertWeek,
```

and :

```
dayRender: function( date, cell ) { 
    // Get the current view     
    var view = $('#meal_calendar').fullCalendar('getView');

    // Check if the view is the new vertWeek - 
    // in case you want to use different views you don't want to mess with all of them
    if (view.name == 'vertWeek') {
        // Hide the widget header - looks wierd otherwise
        $('.fc-widget-header').hide();

        // Remove the default day number with an empty space. Keeps the right height according to your font.
        $('.fc-day-number').html('<div class="fc-vertweek-day">&nbsp;</div>');

        // Create a new date string to put in place  
        var this_date = date.format('ddd, MMM Do');

        // Place the new date into the cell header. 
        cell.append('<div class="fc-vertweek-header"><div class="fc-vertweek-day">'+this_date+'</div></div>');
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks honk. Looks better with the changes and the picture.